# CX_Oracle for python, under Anaconda is not installing

Tags: python, anaconda, cx-oracle

Anaconda keeps telling me that cx_oracle needs python 3.4.

My conda version is 4.3.17

This is after I used the cx_Oracle-5.3-11g.win-amd64-py3.5-2.exe installer. which is supposed to be used for Python 3.5.

```
conda install -c anaconda cx_oracle=5.2
Fetching package metadata ...............
Solving package specifications: .
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
- cx_oracle 5.2* -> python 3.4*
- python 3.5*
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

I'm doing something stupid, but I'm not sure what. yet.
ideas? 
hints?

Answer (score 1):

The error's telling you that the cx_oracle package you're trying to install depends on Python 3.4 b/c that's the currently available build of cx_oracle on the `anaconda` channel.

If you [search for cx_oracle](https://anaconda.org/search?q=cx_oracle) on anaconda.org, you'll see a list of available builds on several other channels, and can look for one that meets your reqs (namely v5.2, Python 3.5, win64). Doesn't look like there's one that meets that *exact* set of reqs, but there are a few v5.21 & v5.3 builds available. If that's close enough, then installing from say, the `amodig` channel may get you going: `conda install -c amodig cx_oracle=5.2.1`

Comment: Use recent versions of Python and the Oracle driver - this was renamed from cx_Oracle to python-oracledb some time ago, see https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/oracledb

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and it seems that you python version and the specified version of cx_oracle are not compatible. Being that the case I would suggest

1. upgrade your python version and get the latest cx_oracle (Recommended, to avoid obsoleted packages)
2. downgrade your python version  to python3.4 and use the version that you want of cx_oracle.
   For the first option, I would

```
conda install python=3.12
conda install conda-forge::cx_oracle
```

For the second option [upgrade/downgrade python in conda](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-python.html#updating-or-upgrading-python)

```
conda install python=3.4
conda install -c conda-forge cx_oracle=5.2
```

3. Another option (highly recommended) would be to create a conda environment, activate it and install into there you required modules.

```
conda create -n your_py34_env python=3.4
conda activate your_py34_env
conda install -c conda-forge cx_oracle=5.2
```

Comment: Note that the "latest cx_oracle" is actually called python-oracledb, see the [release announcement](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a) from a couple of years ago about the renaming.  Also see [Python-oracledb is now installable with conda](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/python-oracledb-is-now-installable-with-conda-34ebe776d7db)